# Streaming files from AWS S3 with Node.js and SDK v3

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I would like to stream a file with the AWS Node.js SDK v3 without downloading it completely first. How to get this stream? In the documentation I only found examples for the complete download, which works, but I don't want it.

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const bareBonesS3 = new S3Client({ region: 'eu-central-1' });
const file = await bareBonesS3.send(
  new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'SOME_BUCKET_NAME',
    Key: 'SOME_OBJECT_KEY',
  }),
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS s3 V3 Javascript SDK stream file from bucket (GetObjectCommand)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366381/aws-s3-v3-javascript-sdk-stream-file-from-bucket-getobjectcommand)

Comment: Awesome @jarmod ! TY :)