# S3Client throws Readable.toWeb() is not supported error when using transformToWebStream

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using NodeJS 14 version. I have the following code to download a file from AWS S3 using aws-sdk version 3.

```
static async downloadFromS3(document: Document) {    
    
    let s3 = new S3Client(config.get<unknown>('S3_CONFIG'));
    
    const bucket = config.get("S3_BUCKET_NAME") as string;
    const bucketKey = document.s3Key;   

    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: bucketKey
    });

    const response = await s3.send(command);
    return response.Body.transformToWebStream();
  }
```

I am trying to write unit test as below using `aws-sdk-client-mock`, 'aws-sdk-client-mock-jest' and '@aws-sdk/util-stream-node' packages. [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-client-mock#s3-getobjectcommand)

```
  import { Readable } from 'stream';
  import { S3Client,HeadObjectCommand, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
  import { mockClient } from "aws-sdk-client-mock";
  import 'aws-sdk-client-mock-jest';
  import {sdkStreamMixin} from '@aws-sdk/util-stream-node';

it('should be able to downloadFromS3()', async () => {

    // create Stream from string
     const stream = new Readable();
     stream.push('hello world');
     stream.push(null); // end of stream

   // wrap the Stream with SDK mixin
     const sdkStream = sdkStreamMixin(stream);    
 
     const mockS3Client = mockClient(S3Client);   
   
    mockS3Client.on(HeadObjectCommand).resolves({
      // Simulated response
    });   

    mockS3Client.on(GetObjectCommand).resolves({Body: sdkStream});

    var result = await downloadFromS3({
      name: 'name',
      s3Key: 's3Key',
    } as Document);

    expect(mockS3Client).toHaveReceivedCommand(HeadObjectCommand);
    expect(mockS3Client).toHaveReceivedCommand(GetObjectCommand);       
  });
```

However unit test throws error when it calls transformToWebStream() method on Body

> "Readable.toWeb() is not supported. Please make sure you are using
> Node.js >= 17.0.0, or polyfill is available."

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67373050/2964811
Briefly - `response.Body` is an instance of `Readable`, so you don't need extra manipulations like `response.Body.transformToWebStream()`.

Answer (score -1):

Update node to version >= 17.0.0.

Comment: There may be cases where this is not possible within the user's given context.