# How to use AWS lambda to transfer s3 object to a remote server

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to use a node.js lambda to retrieve an s3 object. Then I would like to write that to a remote server using the https library.

Where I'm at currently: I have a nodejs lambda that connects to an s3 bucket to retrieve an s3 object. Then it passes a GetObjectCommandOutput to another class to handle the secure transfer of the file. I'm stuck at the following code:

```
public async getFile(record: S3EventRecord) {
  const data: GetObjectCommandOutput = await this.s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: <BucketName>,
    Key: <ObjectKey>,
  }));
  return data;
}
```

Data comes back successfully but I don't know what to do with it in order to allow my lambda to transfer the file from s3 to a remote server. I'm trying to use nodejs https library to do this by passing the data
that's returned in the getFile method to a "SecureTransportHandler" class that should transfer the file to a destination ip address.

```
export class SecureTransportHandler {
    async transferFile(destination: string, path: string, cert: string, data: GetObjectCommandOutput): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            const options = {
                hostname: destination,
                port:443,
                path: path,
                method: 'POST',
                cert: cert,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'curl/8.0.1'
                    'Content-Length': <file length>
                },
            };

            console.log(file.Body);
            const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
                console.log('statusCode', res.statusCode);
                console.log('headers', res.headers);
                let responseBody = '';
                res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
                    responseBody += chunk;
                });

                res.on('end', () => {
                    resolve(responseBody);
                });
            });

            req.on('error', (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });

            req.write(file.Body);
            req.end();            
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the code as I currently have it written I'm getting the following error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received instance of IncomingMessage.

I've tried to implement the solution in [AWS s3 V3 Javascript SDK stream file from bucket (GetObjectCommand)](this [AWS s3 V3 Javascript SDK stream file from bucket (GetObjectCommand)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366381/aws-s3-v3-javascript-sdk-stream-file-from-bucket-getobjectcommand)) but there are errors and my code won't compile so I'm not sure that I'm using it correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this file transfer? Am I even on the correct path?